# Sequence which converges fastest to $\sqrt{x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $a_{1} =1 $ and $a_{n+1}=0.5(a_{n}+x/a_{n})$ with $x \in \mathbb{R} $ and $x>0$ is way to find the root of a number. It converges to $\sqrt{x}$.

What I am wondering know: Is there a sequence which converges even faster to $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: What about $$a_1=1,\quad a_{n+1}=\frac12\left(\frac12(a_n+x/a_n)+\frac x{0.5(a_n+x/a_n)}\right)$$

Comment: The sequence $a_n=\sqrt x$ converges very quickly to $\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you take the sequence $a_1, a_3, a_5, \dots$ clearly this converges faster than $a_1, a_2, a_3$.

There's the stupid case of $a_n = \sqrt{x}$

Otherwise there is a wikipedia page of methods to compute square roots: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Your question in its current state is hard to answer definiteively.